# Gradually increasing speed of scrolling background in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a simple game in SpriteKit, and I have a scrolling background. What simply happens is that a few background images are placed adjacent to each other when the game scene is loaded, and then the image is moved horizontally when it scrolls out of the screen. Here is the code for that, from my game scene's `didMoveToView` method.

```
// self.gameSpeed is 1.0 and gradually increases during the game

let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background")
var moveBackground = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: (20 / self.gameSpeed))
var replaceBackground = SKAction.moveByX(self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 0)
var moveBackgroundForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBackground, replaceBackground]))

for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 2; i++ {
    var background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2 + self.frame.size.width * i, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    background.size = self.frame.size
    background.zPosition = -100
    background.runAction(moveBackgroundForever)

    self.addChild(background)
}
```

Now I want to increase the speed of the scrolling background at certain points of the game. You can see that the duration of the background's horizontal scroll is set to `(20 / self.gameSpeed)`. Obviously this does not work, because this code is only run once, and therefore the movement speed is never updated to account for a new value of the `self.gameSpeed` variable.

So, my question is simply: how do I increase the speed (reduce the duration) of my background images' movements according to the `self.gameSpeed` variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `gameSpeed` variable to set the velocity of the background. For this to work, firstly, you need to have a reference to your two background pieces (or more if you so wanted):

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    lazy var backgroundPieces: [SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background"), 
                                                 SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")]

    // ... 
}
```

Now you need your `gameSpeed` variable:

```
var gameSpeed: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    // Using a property observer means you can easily update the speed of the 
    // background just by setting gameSpeed.
    didSet {
        for background in backgroundPieces {
            // Minus, because the background is moving from left to right.
            background.physicsBody!.velocity.dx = -gameSpeed
        }
    }
}
```

Then position each piece correctly in `didMoveToView`. Also, for this method to work each background piece needs a physics body so you can easily change its velocity.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    for (index, background) in enumerate(backgroundPieces) {
        // Setup the position, zPosition, size, etc...

        background.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: background.size)
        background.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        background.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
        background.physicsBody!.friction = 0

        self.addChild(background)
    }

    // If you wanted to give the background and initial speed,
    // here's the place to do it.
    gameSpeed = 1.0
}
```

You could update `gameSpeed` in `update` for example with `gameSpeed += 0.5`.

Finally, in `update` you need to check if a background piece has gone offscreen (to the left). If it has it needs to be moved to the end of the chain of background pieces:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    for background in backgroundPieces {
        if background.frame.maxX <= 0 {
            let maxX = maxElement(backgroundPieces.map { $0.frame.maxX })

            // I'm assuming the anchor of the background is (0.5, 0.5)
            background.position.x = maxX + background.size.width / 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried to implement this, but I am facing a problem. When the `gameSpeed` variable changes, the velocity is set correctly. However, this velocity gradually decreases over time, meaning that the movement speed of the background gradually slows down. Every time the `gameSpeed` variable is updated, the movement speed of the background is sped up again, but after some time, it seems that the background stops speeding up. However, the main problem is that the background gradually moves more slowly. I tried a few workarounds for this, but I was unable to succeed

Comment: Oh, my bad, I forgot to include the code to remove `linearDamping` and `friction` from the physics bodies, unless you already added that and something else is wrong?

Comment: Great, that fixed the speed gradually decreasing. Now the speed is constant, but there is still one problem. The background starts moving at an initial speed, and after a few seconds, it is sped up by changing the value of the `gameSpeed` variable. So far so good. The problem then occurs when the variable is updated again, at which point the background slows down, even if the value for the velocity should speed it up. So basically it works on the first update of the game speed, but not after that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not getting that problem I'm afraid...The only thing I can think of that might be the problem is you're not incrementing the `gameSpeed`, but instead setting it to a slower value than its current value? If that's not the case we could continue the discussion in chat and get to the bottom of this :)

Comment: The `gameSpeed` variable is incremented by 0.1 every X seconds, and a `println` statement shows that it is incremented correctly. I am multiplying `gameSpeed` by a fixed value when setting the velocity, because otherwise the change in speed is hardly noticeable. Even after the background speed goes back to normal (after being sped up for a while), I can see that the velocity is decreased correctly. Sorry that I didn't see your last comment about the chat yesterday - I will be available later today if you are around. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78198/discussion-between-abakersmith-and-andy0708).

Comment: Awesome, I got it to work thanks to your advice! Thank you so much for going above and beyond to help me out. I owe you one! :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of something like this

```
SKAction.waitforDuration(a certain amount of period to check for the updated values) 

SKAction.repeatActionForever(the action above)
runAction(your action)
{ // this is the completion block, do whatever you want here, check the values and adjust them accordly
}
```

Comment: Also, add code in the repeatActionForever block that changes the value of the wait:

`newWaitValue = functionThatModifiesWait(oldWaitValue)`

If I were to take a stab at a first approximation for the function, I'd try an inverse elliptic.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. Your pseudo-code runs a code block every X seconds. In that code block, I would need to update the `moveBackground` action (see the question) in order to change the speed, right? The issue is not updating the `self.gameSpeed` variable, it is to apply new game speeds to the speed of the scrolling background. Perhaps you could provide a bit more details, because I'm a bit confused. Sorry.

Comment: In the pseduo-code block that I provided, you could update the self.gameSpeed variable after a certain amount of X seconds. Or are you trying to increase the gameSpeed after certain special events?

Comment: Also I uploaded a short example which I used last time over here http://pastebin.com/NVCzPR1s