# SpriteKit. How to change the background speed?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Recently began to study spratkite. I ran into a question.
Created a moving background. How to change its speed?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class BgDeceleration {
    //Background Speed 

    var bgDuration : Double = 5

   //Toggle

    var bgToggle = true {

        willSet {bgDuration = bgToggle ? 5.0 : 10.0}

        didSet {}

    }

}

let course = bgDeceleration()

class GameScene: SKScene {


    //Textures

    var bgTexture: SKTexture!

    //Sprite Nodes

    var bg = SKSpriteNode()

    //Sprite Objects

    var bgObject = SKNode()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        //Background Textures

        bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")

        createObjects()

        createGame()

    }


    func createObjects() {

        self.addChild(bgObject)

    }

    func createGame() {

        createBg()

    }


    func createBg() {

        bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")   

        let moveBg = SKAction.moveBy(x: -bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: bgDeceleration.bgDuration)

        let replaceBg = SKAction.moveBy(x: bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)

        let moveBgForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBg, replaceBg]))

        for i in 0..<3 {

            bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)

            bg.position = CGPoint(x: bgTexture.size().width * CGFloat(i), y: size.height/2.0)

            bg.size.height = self.frame.height

            bg.run(moveBgForever)

            bg.zPosition = -1

            bgObject.addChild(bg)

        }
    }
}

extension GameScene {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        //Toggle

        bgDeceleration.bgToggle.toggle()

    }

}
```

Found a solution. But it does not work
[Gradually increasing speed of scrolling background in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226379/gradually-increasing-speed-of-scrolling-background-in-spritekit)
possibly because of the swift version.
please share the solution if possible

Comment: Increase `var bgDuration : Double = 5` to `var bgDuration : Double = 10`?

Comment: Yes. Speed slows down twice and back @aheze